# Stored procedure to return two datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following existing stored procedure and would like it to return two datasets. Details as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_OrderByPhone]
    @Phone varchar(15),
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT O.ID, O.Type, O.Business, O.TimeXStamp, O.RefNum
    FROM Order O
    INNER JOIN Customer C ON O.ID = C.ID
    WHERE C.SelPhone = @Phone
    ORDER BY O.TimeXStamp DESC      
END
```

I can run it as

```
exec GET_OrderByPhone '123-456-8888'
```

It returns this result

```
ID | Type | Business | Timestamp  | RefNum
---+------+----------+------------+---------
1  | xx   | yy       | 2020-01-01 | zz
```

Now, I have to add another query in same stored procedure which will return multiple rows as a separate table. My new table is as,

```
VehicleTable
------------

ID | Type | Text 
---+------+-------
1  |  8   | Honda
1  |  9   | Civic
1  | 10   | Black
```

It has the ID column which is same is above stored procedure. So when I run the stored procedure, it will return two datasets, one as it is already happening, and second with three rows (which is fixed for each vehicle) from vehicle table.

Comment: . . Do you have a question?

Comment: Question is, how to return multiple dataset from SP I have. Sorry if it confused you.

Comment: With an additional `SELECT`.

Comment: Would it be join or without ?

Comment: Could you explain the business use case to return multiple datasets from a stored procedure. You could add a SELECT * FROM VehicleTable. It Could be any SELECT statement with or without a join.

Comment: `SELECT 1 AS One; SELECT 2 AS Two;`There, you have 2 datasets. SPs are no different.

Comment: If you see clearly SP takes argument as Phone, but third table has to use ID column to get those details.

Comment: What if a phone number is attached to two customer IDs?

Comment: Its is taken care in UI, it will show Order with multiple phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use temporary table :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_OrderByPhone]
    @Phone varchar(15),
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     IF Object_ID('tempdb_..#Orders') DROP TABLE #Orders

     SELECT O.ID, O.Type, O.Business, O.TimeXStamp, O.RefNum INTO #Orders
     FROM Order O INNER JOIN 
          Customer C 
          ON O.ID = C.ID
     WHERE C.SelPhone = @Phone
     ORDER BY O.TimeXStamp DESC 

     SELECT O.*
     FROM #Orders O

     SELECT v.*
     FROM #Vehicles v
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #orders o WHERE o.id = v.id);

DROP TABLE #Orders

END
```

Comment: Perfect @Yogesh !

Comment: @Ris. . . You might requires some index on temp tables.